# React & Cloudflare issue

Tags: reactjs, ssl, cloudflare, cdn

I added Cloudflare to my React webpage and ever since I've been experiencing a very weird issue - on Safari, loading the page for the first time results in a black page - it doesn't load the js & css chucks. Refreshing once or twice results in the website being loaded normally. I tested on Chrome & Opera - it doesn't happen - it's Safari only both web and mobile. I removed the SSL certificates I had and I'm using the global one provided by Cloudflare and I think it could be related, but I'm kinda stumbled. Anyone experienced something like that? Here's a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/ouLWTQ0_Aek